# Stop third party from sending push notification

Tags: javascript, php, web, push-notification, push

I added a third party push ad service. They told me to add a javascript script in the `<head>` of my website and they told me to download the `sw.js` file in the web root. When any visitor visits the site, they prompt the push notification allow/deny dialog, and when someone allows, they send push notification using my site.

But I noticed that they are sending adult notification to my users and I removed their code and the `sw.js` file, but they are still sending adult and scam AD notification to my users. They are ruining the reputation of my site. I don't know what I should do. How do I stop them from doing this?

Comment: Stop using that service maybe?

Comment: @ user3532758 That service does not have that feature.

Comment: Then I would boldly assume that your website is compromised. Sorry. Have a security scan done. As for push, if the said third party is malicious, they would already have your users' device ids to target their own notifications.

Comment: @ user3532758 I need to stop that don't I? Isn't there one single solution to stop them using my domain? I don't use their code anymore. Now the push prompt is gone, but they still have the old endpoint and keys with them to send push notification to my users using my domain name.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli  Don't you think push notification is part of programming? Isn't there really a solution to this?

Comment: @fastANDfurious sure, push notifications can be part of programming something. This question is definitely not about programming though.